# How to find if a port is enabled on a webserver

Tags: php, port, web-hosting

A noob question:

I want to enable Google Cloud Messaging  on my website being hosted on godaddy. I want to determine if port 5228 (to be used by GCM) is enabled by godaddy and if I can go ahead and implement GCM.

How can I find it out? I tried the following code:

```
<?php
    $host = 'mysite.com';
    $ports = array(5228, 5229, 5230);    
foreach ($ports as $port)
{
$errno  = null;
$errstr = null;

$connection = @fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr);

if (is_resource($connection)) {
    echo '<h2>' . $host . ':' . $port . ' ' . '(' . getservbyport($port, 'tcp') . ') is open.</h2>' . "\n";
    fclose($connection);
} else {
    echo "<h2>{$host}:{$port} is not responding. Error {$errno}: {$errstr} </h2>" . "\n";
}
```

}
    ?>

I got following result:

```
mysite.com:5228 is not responding. Error 111: Connection refused
mysite.com:5229 is not responding. Error 111: Connection refused
mysite.com:5230 is not responding. Error 111: Connection refused
```

Does this mean that goDaddy will not allow me to implement GCM as 5228 is not enabled? Or does it mean that my firewall(or ISP) is not letting me connect to tehe website at port 5228?

Thanks

p.s.: I know there are many questions regarding this topic, I did surf them but was not able to get a definitive answer.

Comment: Hi wasnt just about goDaddy...needed a generic way to find out in case I moved from godaddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ports 5228, 5229, 5230 are needed by android devices, not by the server that is going to push notifications to GCM.

If you want to check if your server will connect to GCM, try to create a POST HTTP request to GCM: https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send

BTW your code is trying to connect to mysite.com, not to GCM

Comment: I was connecting to mysite.com as I thought that the server needed to have the ports open... but you answered my query... thanks.